# How to create ListBox with code only?

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I googled a lot but I had absolutely no luck finding anything about my problem.

I would like to create `ListBox` - just like the one anyone can create using UserForms. The problem is that I do not want to draw it but write it with a code. I know how to add values to ListBox etc. The only thing I am missing is how to create it programatically.

I found this: [Creating form programmatically in the module using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519345/creating-form-programmatically-in-the-module-using-vba) but this code didn't work for me. It stops at declaring Forms.

The idea behind this ListBox is to create a ListBox to choose from sheets in a workbook to later do some stuff.

Comment: Read up more on `Me.Controls.Add`. See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224511/assign-code-to-a-button-created-dynamically-using-vba-on-excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Me.Controls.Add ("Forms.Listbox.1")
```

allows you to [add a control at runtime only](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/157319) using an event procedure.

Comment: Is this necessary to use Forms? Module alone cannot handle it?

Comment: hm.. sorry what do you mean?

Comment: I was wondering if ListBox can be created without using Forms - UserForm. Because your code will work in Userform but when i paste it to Module it will not. I wanted to write whole code in one place and bypass - if possible - UserForm.

Comment: Hm. have you seen the `resolution` part of [THIS LINK](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/157319) ? Is that what you are after?