# VBA Excel - Update control on a dynamicaly addressed userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of userforms with static controls on them. I have created a Class Module to apply event handlers to a set of texboxes I am dynamically adding to the userform. When I specifically address a userform from the Class Module I can update the value in the static controls...

```
IAFStep2c.Controls("chkOptIn").Value = True
```

But when I try to update the controls with their userform's name in a variable it doesn't work...

```
Dim oUserFOrm As Object
Dim formName As String
formName = "IAFStep2c"
Set oUserFOrm = UserForms.Add(formName)
oUserFOrm.Controls("chkOptIn").Value = True
```

I can read the value and other properties of the controls, just not update them. Can someone offer a solution to this?

EDIT

I created another spreadsheet with the class below, same result. TextBox1 and 3 get updated, textBox2 does not.

```
Sub doStuff()
'MsgBox ("ping")
Dim oUserFOrm As Object
Dim formName As String
formName = "frmTest"
Set oUserFOrm = UserForms.Add(formName)
frmTest.Controls("TextBox1").Value = oUserFOrm.Controls("TextBox2").Name
oUserFOrm.Controls("TextBox2").Value = "PING"
frmTest.Controls("TextBox3").Value = oUserFOrm.Controls("TextBox2").TextAlign
```

End Sub

Comment: Why someone downvoted this question? It's properly formulated!

Comment: I can't reproduce such of behaviour. What version of MS Excel? What's error message? Have you tried to export userform, delete it and import it again? Can you show your class definition?

Comment: Excel 2013. There is no error message, it just fails to update the field and continues on as if nothing happened. Not tried export/import of the form, I'm new to this so any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: `UserForms.Add(formName)` will **Add** the UserForm as a **new** UserForm to memory. It takes the UserForm from designer with properties and values provided in designer. It will **not** get an already shown UserForm.

Comment: Thanks Axel, that makes sense. Still haven't found how to get an already shown userform :(

Comment: Please show how the UserForm will be shown. Why you can't assign the UserForm to a variable before it is shown (`formName = "frmTest" : Set oUserFOrm = UserForms.Add(formName)`) and then show it via `oUserFOrm.Show`?

Comment: We need to see a class definition to be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Axel, I think you have the answer. I was just getting excel to open the forms on file opening but if I do it as you suggest I'll have a handle on it to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:

```
UserForm1.Controls("Textbox1").Text = "123"
```

At least it works by me, when I am trying it. Office 2010.

Comment: Using the form name directly works for me as well, it's when I'm trying to get the form name out of a variable that it's not happening

Comment: Ok. So the idea is to create a form and to manipulate a textbox in a userform which is just created? However, take a look at this answer here, probably you would find what you need:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519345/creating-form-programmatically-in-the-module-using-vba