# How to add a dynamic label in a VBA userform and assign a specific cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

In the code below I am adding a label "dLblQty" on the click of save button on the userform. And this button needs to be assigned a value from Cell A27 then A28 and so on in each iteration of button press.
But this gives a Runtime error  '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.
Please suggest correct way of doing this.

Below is the snippet:

```
Dim strCap As String

strCap = Worksheets("Tax Invoice - Intra State").Range("A1").Value

Dim dLblQty As Control
Set dLblQty = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "dLblQty", True)
With dLblQty
    .Top = 20
    .Left = 20
    .MultiLine = True
    .Height = 100
    .Caption = strCap
End With
```

Comment: Why change the cell you take the value from on each click? If it is the last value in that column, look into using the concept of Lastrow.

Comment: `.EnterKeyBehavior` only seems to be a valid property for TextBox controls: https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/enterkeybehavior-property

Comment: @J.Fox Yes I agree. So removed .Enterkeybehavior property now. But my question still exists.

Comment: When I tried your code without `.EnterKeyBehavior = True` in it, it ran fine without erroring. Were you still encountering an error?

Comment: If i am correct, you are adding Controls to a Userform, look here for an example to make it: [Creating form programmatically in the module using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519345/creating-form-programmatically-in-the-module-using-vba)

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because the Label control doesn't have a `multiline` property or method. The rest of the snippet functions perfectly.

Comment: Weirdly enough, it ran fine for me with `.MultiLine = True` still in there when I tried it earlier, but *now* it's erroring. I wonder why it would error sometimes but not others?

Answer (score 0):

The code certainly gives no errors on removing multiline and enterkeybehavior as these are textbox properties. But this didn't solve my problem of adding a dynamic label and dynamically assigning a cell value to it.

After trying a few times, I understood what I was doing wrong.
I declared my label as an object of MSForms.label class and this did the trick. Below is the solution:

```
Dim strCap As String
Dim dLblItem As MSForms.Label

strCap = Worksheets("Tax Invoice - Intra State").Range("B1").Value

Set dLblItem = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "dLblItem", True)
With dLblItem
    .Top = 20
    .Left = 20
    '.MultiLine = True
    '.EnterKeyBehavior = True
    .Height = 100
    .Caption = strCap
    .BackColor = &HFF&
    .ForeColor = &H8000&
End With
```