Excel complete crash with creating dynamic frame
I have a userform with 3 frames on it. I am trying to read a worksheet to determine which frame data should be added to. Then it creates a frame dynamically inside the selected parent frame and adds a command button and label inside the child frame. My issue is that excel is crashing on line Set Frame = Framesel.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "Fr_" & JobNum). No matter what error handling method I use I don't know what the issue is, I get no error messages, nothing will print to the immediate, it just the crashes.
Dim ColEvents As Collection
Dim DynamicFrames As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Set DynamicFrames = New Collection

    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
    Set Ws1 = Worksheets("Job")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Ws1.Cells(Ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim FindResult As Range
    Dim NumCol As Long
    Dim NoteCol As Long
    Dim AuthCol As Long
    Dim L As Long
    L = Ws1.Cells(1, Ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    With Ws1.Range("A1", Ws1.Cells(1, L))
        Set FindResult = .Find("generated_job_id", LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then NumCol = FindResult.Column
        
        Set FindResult = .Find("customfield_permanent_notes", LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then NoteCol = FindResult.Column
        
        Set FindResult = .Find("customfield_photo_release_authorized", LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then AuthCol = FindResult.Column
    End With
    
    Dim x As Long
    Dim Framesel As MSForms.Frame
    Dim JobNum As String
    Dim AuthString As String
    Dim NoteString As String
    Dim Label As MSForms.Label
    Dim CommandButton As MSForms.CommandButton

    For x = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        JobNum = Ws1.Cells(x, NumCol).Value
        AuthString = Ws1.Cells(x, AuthCol).Value
        NoteString = Ws1.Cells(x, NoteCol).Value
        
        Select Case CStr(AuthString)
            Case "Yes": Set Framesel = FrAuthorized
            Case "No": Set Framesel = FrUnauthorized
            Case Else: Set Framesel = FrVerify
        End Select
        
        If Framesel Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Error: Framesel is not assigned correctly."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        On Error Resume Next
        
        Dim Frame As MSForms.Frame
        Set Frame = Framesel.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "Fr_" & JobNum)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Error adding frame: " & Err.Description
            Err.Clear
            On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        With Frame
            .Left = 10
            .Top = 5
            .Width = 300
            .Height = 30
            .Caption = ""
        End With
        
        DynamicFrames.Add Frame, "Fr_" & JobNum
        
        Set CommandButton = Frame.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "CB_" & JobNum)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Error adding command button: " & Err.Description
            Err.Clear
            On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        With CommandButton
            .Caption = JobNum
            .Top = 5
            .Width = 25
            .Left = 10
            .Font.Size = 11
            .Height = 20
        End With
        
        SetCommandClickEvent CommandButton.Object
        
        Set Label = Frame.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Lbl_" & JobNum)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Error adding label: " & Err.Description
            Err.Clear
            On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        With Label
            .Left = 30
            .Top = 5
            .Width = 250
            .Font.Size = 11
            .Caption = NoteString
            .TextAlign = 2
        End With
        
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next x
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
End Sub

Private Sub SetCommandClickEvent(ByVal btn As MSForms.CommandButton)
    On Error Resume Next
    
    If ColEvents Is Nothing Then Set ColEvents = New Collection
    
    Dim CommandButtonEventHandler As APICallNamesClass
    Set CommandButtonEventHandler = New APICallNamesClass
    Set CommandButtonEventHandler.CommandButton = btn
    
    ColEvents.Add CommandButtonEventHandler
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error setting command click event: " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

With further testing I have found this to be a truly unique issue. Since I have this exact code in another workbook, which works with no issues, and I just copied the code over it should be working. I also figured out that when I place a new generic frame on the user form and don't change anything from the default settings it works. When I name it, change font, basically any customizing of properties either programmatically or through the property window it causes excel to crashes. If I add a second generic frame it also crashes.
When I step through it gets to the Set Frame = Framesel.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "Fr_" & JobNum) line, then the userform goes blank white and sits there for a couple seconds. It then crashes excel completely with no error, messages or warnings. It looks like excel is getting caught in a loop until it runs out of memory and shuts down. I have tried to break the code during this time, and check for system errors. There is nothing being recorded.
I am thinking of just switching to dynamically creating the user form and frames, this works with no issues.

(1) Try to move the routine to a later event, eg to UserForm_Activate (2) I find it usually easier to create all controls during design time. Just either show/hide them depending on your needs.

Can you post just bare-bones code that allows us to replicate your problem? The code you posted doesn't allow us to do that because it relies on specific data to be present in our file.

Maybe designing the form should be done prior to loading it. This answer might provide some guidance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519345/create-userform-programmatically-in-the-module-using-vba

FunThomas - I have already tried this to no Aval.

jkpieterse - This is a bear-bones edition. All you need is a worksheet with 3 columns, 1- header "generated_job_id" with 4 digit numbers, 2 - header "customfield_permanent_notes" with any text, 3 - header "customfield_photo_release_authorized" with Yes, No or Empty. There is a lot more, this is what I striped it to so I could figure out what is happening.

bugdown - The form is already built in the design window. This code is just to add the dynamic portions that change every time it is loaded.

I have also edited the question and add more information about what is happening.

@Hareborn You said you copied the code over. Have you tried copying the entire userform over, dragging it to the other workbook in the project pane?

Yes, I did try copying the userform over.

Due to time constraints I am forced to scrab the userform. So I am closing this question.
